# Azure Function is extremely slow with BLOCKED_TIME on ProcessMonitoringModule

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm running an Azure Function with very basic code as follows:

```cs
string validationToken = req.Query["validationToken"];

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationToken))
{
    await Task.CompletedTask;
    return new OkObjectResult(validationToken);
}

return new BadRequestResult();
```

But my response times are too slow around the 95th percentile and above. I ran the profiler and it shows the slowest module is `ProcessMonitoringModule`.

[image: Azure Profiling]

Even without running the profiler, the results are pretty much the same. Here's the result from Apache JMeter on the same endpoint.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Turning off the custom auto-heal** feature in the diagnostic setting made it work!

Custom Auto-Heal description:

[image]

Load Test:
[image]

---

**Previous Answer:**

Thanks to technical support from Azure, it seems that the Azure Storage extension needed to be upgraded.

Though I didn't have a direct dependency, I **updated Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions to 3.0.9** and it works!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is due cold start. You'll get better results when moving to Premium Plan:

More info in here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan

Comment: This function is already in Premium Plan with 14GB mem! And also I created a consumption plan Azure Function and even with cold-start the max time is around 3 secs

Comment: go to diagnose and solve issues in your app plan, it should give some insights. I believe some requests are being queued which increase the response time while the ones in the queue are being processed

Comment: If that is the case then shouldn't it happen in all azure functions the same way? When I create a new Azure Function (both consumption & premium) with the same runtime (~3) and deploy the same code, there's no such lag.

Comment: Also, the screenshot above is from profiler under "diagnose and solve issues"!